# Form seemingly not returning post values or saving to DB on Django

Tags: django

I've found several posts with questions practically identical to this, but I've spent many hours trying to figure out my problem based on these posts and just cannot for the life of me figure this out. I am trying to take values from a form and put them into my database (and then list what's in the database underneath my form, but that's more for me to see if it's working). It seems that either the form values aren't being extracted or I'm not properly saving to the database.

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Users(models.Model):
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['user_first_name', 'user_last_name', 'email_address']
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from manage_users.models import Users, UserForm

def index(request):
    users_list = Users.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_first_name = request.POST.get('user_first_name', '')
            user_last_name = request.POST.get('user_last_name', '')
            email_address = request.POST.get('email_address', '')
            users_obj = Users(user_first_name=user_first_name, user_last_name=user_last_name, email_address=email_address)
            users_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'form': form, 'users_list': users_list
        })
```

And lastly, my html:

```
<body>
        <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <label for="user_first_name">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user_first_name" />
                <br><label for="user_last_name">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user_last_name" />
                <br><label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email_address" />
            </div>
            <button id ="add" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        {% if users_list %}
            <ul>
                {% for user in users_list %}
                    <li>{{ user }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No users are currently in the system</p>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Rohan's answer: you are instantiating the form correctly, but then you are ignoring it. You are not using it either to save the fields, or display the errors in the template. That is completely missing the point of using one in the first place.

The reason your form is not saving is certainly because you have a validation error. But since you are not outputting the form in itself in the template, you will never know. You can use `{{ form.as_p }}` instead of all those manually defined `<input>`s and `<label>`s. Plus, by doing this you will not only see the errors, but those fields that are valid will be pre-populated with the data previously entered.

Secondly, as Rohan says, you are ignoring the form data when your form is valid. `cleaned_data` contains the validated, clean data - with things like IntegerFields converted to actual integers. It is an attribute not a method, and is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data). But for a model form, you don't even need that: you should just do:

```
if form.is_valid():
    users_obj = form.save()
    return ....
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ModelForm` you don't need to create object that way, you can just do `form.save()` to add data in DB.

If you want to refer to data that is `POST`ed use `form.cleaned_data` rather than `request.POST`.

Refer the [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) documentation for more details

To Give sample code:

```
def index(request):
    users_list = Users.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Method 1
                user_obj = form.save() 
            #Method 2 - use form.cleaned_data
                user_first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('user_first_name', '')
                user_last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('user_last_name', '')
                email_address = form.cleaned_data.get('email_address', '')
                users_obj = Users(user_first_name=user_first_name,
                          user_last_name=user_last_name, 
                          email_address=email_address)
                users_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'form': form, 'users_list': users_list
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the form.save() tip. I'm still confused on getting the data though. Are you saying I should do something like form = UserForm() and not use request.POST? Additionally, I don't see a clearned_data method in the ModelForm documentation.